# How to plot DataFrame column value in different shape based on other column value

Tags: python, plot, dataframe

I am still new to python plot. Let us say I have created a dataframe as follows for demo.
What I want to do is to

(1) plot the 'value' column value in different color&symbol based on the label column in one figure, i.e, in different groups in the hope of finding different pattern.

(2) cluster each group (based on label column) into different bins(e.g, 5 bins and 3 bin respectively) and put them in a new figure.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
theta = 0.3
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 100)
group = np.random.binomial(1, theta, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([s,group]).transpose())
df.columns = ['value','label']
```

Comment: against what are you plotting 'value column'. Is it just points on 1 dimension with each point having color according to label

Comment: @Shantanu Deshpande, yeah, different color is the minimal, if different symbols as well would be better